# Autocomplete friend list on social engine is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, json, socialengine

I am developing a suggestion functionality for a SocialEngine website. I have written following code on a textbox to give suggestions on the basis of text inserted. But the inject method is not being called for all the results returned by controller. It is skipping some of them. I expect it to call once for each result. Here is the code -

```
new Autocompleter.Request.JSON('global_search_field', '<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'public', 'action' => 'suggest','message' => true), 'default', false) ?>', {          
        'minLength': 1,
        'delay' : 50,
        'className': 'message-autosuggest',
        'injectChoice': function(token){
             console.log("called");
          if(token.type == 'user'){
            console.log("User");
            var choice = new Element('li', {
              'class': 'autocompleter-choices',
              'id':token.guid
            });
            new Element('div', {
              'html': '<a id="'+token.id+'" href="'+token.url+'">'+token.photo+this.markQueryValue(token.label)+'</a>',
              'class': 'autocompleter-choice'
            }).inject(choice);
          }
          else {
              console.log("Heading");
            var choice = new Element('li', {
              'class': 'autocompleter-choices',
              'id':token.guid
            });

            new Element('div', {
                'html': '<a class="menu-heading" style="margin:-9px;" id="'+token.id+'" >'+this.markQueryValue(token.id)+'</a>',
                'class': 'autocompleter-choice'
            }).inject(choice);
          }
          this.addChoiceEvents(choice).inject(this.choices);
            choice.store('autocompleteChoice', token);     
        },
        'onPush' : function(){
         if( $('toValues').value.split(',').length >= maxRecipients ){
            $('to').disabled = true;
          }
        }
    });
```

I have checked the data returned from controller, it is returning multiple results, but some how injector is only getting called for less number of results.

**Update -** 
Injector method is being called for first 10 values returned from controller only

Answer (score 0):

You're working with an instance of `Autocompleter` class. You can find its source code in `/externals/autocompleter/Autocompleter.js`. Pay attention to `maxChoices: 10` variable. You will notice that it limits amount of operations below in code. All you need to do is to override value of this variable to whatever you need.